# Text Widget not clearing with delete function

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter

I'm creating a tkinter gui app and one of my frames has a text widget that calls a function and prints its output onto the widget. Right now i have a button called "activeAlarmButton" that prints properly onto the widget but it doesn't delete the content when i call my clearText() function. I've tried various formats of the delete function parameters but no luck. It just prints the same output under the old one everytime i press the button. My other buttons aren't finished yet, i just want to get this one working first.

```
class logsPage(tk.Frame):
def __init__(self, parent, controller):
    tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)

    activeAlarmButton = tk.Button(self, text = "Active Alarms", width=25, command = lambda: [clearText(), showActiveAlarms()])
    activeAlarmButton.configure(bg = "light yellow")
    activeAlarmButton.grid(column=1, row=1)

    allAlarmButton = tk.Button(self, text = "All Alarms", width=25)
    allAlarmButton.configure(bg = "light yellow")
    allAlarmButton.grid(column=1, row=2)

    backButton = tk.Button(self, text = "Go Back", width=25)
    backButton.configure(bg = "light yellow")
    backButton.grid(column=1, row=3)

    alarmText = tk.Text(self, borderwidth=3, relief="sunken")
    alarmText.configure(font=("Courier", 12), undo=True, wrap="word")
    alarmText.grid(column=2, row = 1, rowspan=3)

    sys.stdout = TextRedirector(alarmText, "stdout")

    self.grid_rowconfigure(0, weight=2)
    self.grid_rowconfigure(4, weight=1)
    self.grid_columnconfigure(0, weight=1)
    self.grid_columnconfigure(3, weight=1)

    self.configure(background='light blue')

    def clearText():
        alarmText.delete('1.0', 'end')
        alarmText.update()



class TextRedirector(object):
def __init__(self, widget, tag="stdout"):
    self.widget = widget
    self.tag = tag

def write(self, str):
    self.widget.configure(state="normal")
    self.widget.insert("end", str, (self.tag,))
    self.widget.configure(state="disabled")

def flush(self):
    pass
```

Comment: When I fix all the problems necessary to make your code run, `clearText` works just fine for me. Maybe `TextRedirector` is causing problems. Without being able to duplicate your problem, we're probably not going to be able to help. Please consider making a proper [mcve]

Comment: You're right it is TextRedirector, whenever i write to the text widget after changing sys.stdout It makes the widget uneditable, but if I type in the text widget and then call clearText it works. I updated my post to show the TextRedirector class which is funny because i got the class from one of your comments on another post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that the `TextRedirector` class keeps the state of the text widget as `disabled`. To delete the text you first need do exactly what `TextRedirector` does: set the state to `normal`, perform the actions on the text widget, then state the state back to `disabled`.

Example:

```
def clearText():
    alarmText.configure(state='normal')
    alarmText.delete('1.0', 'end')
    alarmText.configure(state='disabled')
```

Comment: I understood how it works, i just didn't see it as it being an inconvenience for me until i realized i needed to clear the text, but thank you for your help :)